# shell script to execute command multiple times reading values from input file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a input file, input.txt, and I want to run a command which should read two values from input.txt. Let us assume source name and destination name should be read from input and same command to be iterated thousands times based on input.txt.

Also the output of the command for each is to be stored in separate log. Is this possible with a singular input file or we need to use 2 files for source and destination? Request you to provide shell script to be used to achieve this as I am poor in shell scripting. I tried the below which is not working.

```
while read i j; do
  command $i $j
done > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Suppose this is `input.txt`:

```
source1.txt dest1.txt
source2.txt dest2.txt
...
```

And you want to do this:

```
command source1.txt dest1.txt
command source2.txt dest2.txt
...
```

Here's a way:

```
while read i o; do
    command $i $o
done < input.txt
```

This assumes that command `command` is already constructed to read from it's first argument and write to its second. If `command` instead prints to stdout (i.e., to the terminal screen), then replace `command $i $o` with `command $i > $o`. This also assumes that there are no spaces or funny characters in `input.txt`.

There is also a way that will be significantly faster if your `input.txt` has e.g. millions of lines or more:

```
awk '{printf "command %s\n", $0}' input.txt | sh
```

Or, if you must use `command $i > $o`:

```
awk '{printf "command %s > %s\n", $1, $2}' input.txt | sh
```

This method reads lines from input.txt and prints `command source1.txt dest1.txt` for the first line, `command source2.txt dest2.txt` for the second, etc... Then it "pipes" (`|`) those commands to sh, which executes them.

For error handling in `command`, try:

```
while read i o; do
    command $i $o || command2 $i $o >> command2.log
done < input.txt 2> error.log
```

Or:

```
done < input.txt > error.log 2>&1
```

(One of these will work better, depending on whether `command` and `command2` print their errors to stdout(1) or stderr(2).)

Comment: Thanks Webb, I tried it it works. but i had failures in some commands, is there any way we can check result and if it fails we should run command with slight modification there itself. Also after every command executes the log details to be loaded into a log file. Like below                                       while read i o; do 
    command $i $o 
 if result(good)
 next iteration 
 else 
 command2 $i $o 
done < input.txt > output log.txt

Answer (score 0):

Say you want different outputs in different files, then on log file per command and one error file per command:

```
while read i o; do
  command $i $o 2>"$i$o.err" >"$i$o.log"
done < input.txt
```

Error and log in same file: `stderr` is redirected to `stdout` thanks to `2>&1`:

```
while read i o; do
  command $i $o 2>&1 >"$i$o.log"
done < input.txt
```

You can also have all in same file `output.log`:

```
echo "" > output.log
while read i o; do
  command $i $o 2>&1 >> output.log
done < input.txt
```